# Transfer data from computer through USB to digital potentiometer and back

Tags: usb, digital-potentiometer

I have a robotic device manually controlled by several digital potentiometers. I am also manually taking readings from my potentiometers. Now I want to control my device from computer through USB port. What is the best way to transfer digital data from digital potentiometer(s) to computer using USB and back? Where do I start?
Thank you,
Andrew

PS
I am very new in electronics. Please give me an answer “for dummies.”
Andrew

Comment: Simplest way - through an Arduino or similar device.  How are you controlling the digital potentiometers at the moment?

Comment: How do digipots perform "manual" control?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a custom usb Peripheral. You can use standard USB CDC (the usb to serial protocol) and have a microcontroller interpret commands sent through a virtual com port to control the digital pots and push back results.